# netstat -e: high discards and errors

Tags: windows, networking, internet, netstat

I think my network is congested because of the relatively large discards and errors data. They should be zero or at least close to that.

Here is the output of netstat -e on my computer:

```
Interface Statistics

                           Received            Sent

Bytes                     810900096        72544495
Unicast packets              695440          505220
Non-unicast packets            1692           13352
Discards                 1924553324      1924553324
Errors                   4054803476       619997124
Unknown protocols                 0
```

Here is my setup:

```
ISP > Modem/Router > Computer
```

I think I should just mention that our connection is dsl and we signed a bundled package - telephone + internet. The data is then filtered and goes through a splitter. I am not sure
if that contributes to the problem, though, but every time someone uses the telephone the connection gets disrupted very often. Our connection is very unstable, too. Specially when it is raining.

Comment: Call your provider's support line. My first guess would be a problem with the splitter or you really use VoIP instead of POTS and this traffic eats to much of your bandwidth.

Comment: Errors at or before the router would not be shown there. You are seeing transmission errors on the computer you are at. NIC card might be dying.

Comment: I just disabled then re-enabled the network interface card. The Discards and Errors went to zero. That just reset those values, I believe. I hope my NIC is not dying. Might be the unstable connection.

Comment: How your computer is connected to the router? Please install `mtr` program and run it by `mtr -s 1500 8.8.8.8`. Show results of this command in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a speed negociation problem. By disabling and re-enabling the card, the correct speed was set.